# Need guidance in inserting single record into target table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple records in source table. I have to insert the record from source table to target table. For this, I need to sequence all the records based on `ITEM_NO` and take the last `NOT NULL` values for `ITEM_SEARCH_CATEGORY` column.

If there are totally 5 records coming from source and if fifth record for `ITEM_SEARCH_CATEGORY` is `NULL`, then I need to take the fourth record and insert into the target table.

Similarly if the last 2 records for the `ITEM_SEARCH_CATEGORY` column is `NULL`, then I need to take the 3rd record and insert that it into target table.

How to write the correct query for this logic?

```
ID          DATE          ITEM_NO        ITEM_SEARCH_CATEGORY
12538648    2022-03-03    201            itemsearch:input:suggestion
12538648    2022-03-03    175            NULL
12538648    2022-03-03    160            itemsearch:standard
12538648    2022-03-03    213            itemsearch:input:suggestion
12538648    2022-03-03    198            NULL
```

I have tried the below but I don't think this seems to be right.

```
SELECT distinct
    ID,
    DATE,
    ITEM_NO,
    ITEM_SEARCH_CATEGORY
FROM TABLE_1 A JOIN TABLE_2 B
ON B.IID=A.IID
WHERE DATE='2021-11-06'
    AND ID=12538648
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by ID order by DATE desc) = 1
```

Comment: did you try putting a filter to exclude WHERE ITEM_SEARCH_CATEGORY is NOT NULL and see if it works

Comment: Check usage of LAG - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html#examples

Comment: I didn't try putting ITEM_SEARCH_CATEGORY is not null. I will check that.

Comment: Is it possible to use LAST_VALUE function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are WINDOW functions like LAST_VALUE, LAG, MAX, MIN that pick for this column one value base on logic of the function. And in Snowflake they have a nice IGNORE NULLS clause thus:

| GROUPS | ORDERS | VALUES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 100 |
| a | 2 | 200 |
| a | 3 | null |
| b | 1 | 101 |
| b | 2 | 201 |
| b | 3 | 301 |

for we can `PARTITION BY groups` and then `ORDER BY orders` and get the LAST_VALUE

aka

```
LAST_VALUE(values) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARITION BY groups ORDER BY orders) as values
```

and insert that into a table, but they are "per row" selecting the LAST_VALUE, thus if we select everything from our TABLE, and the LAST_VALUE as define by the SQL, we would have

| GROUPS | ORDERS | VALUES | LAST_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 100 | 200 |
| a | 2 | 200 | 200 |
| a | 3 | null | 200 |
| b | 1 | 101 | 301 |
| b | 2 | 201 | 301 |
| b | 3 | 301 | 301 |

So WINDOW FUNCTIONs select a single value of a WINDOW of future/prior ROWS for this column.

Then we would have the problem of selecting/filter those row down to JUST one row. So you could use DISTINCT which you have done in many places. OR you could use a WHERE clause or QUALIFY. But you have to think what other values of the row are you wanting.

So for the example data, do you want to insert into your results, the values

| GROUPS | ORDERS | VALUES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 200 |
| b | 3 | 301 |

which is the last row, with the LAST_VALUE of VALUES, or do you want, or it could also the the MAX(ORDERS), MAX(VALUES)

or do you want the related details of the row with the largest VALUES that is not null, aka

| GROUPS | ORDERS | VALUES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 200 |
| b | 3 | 301 |

At which point you will need some form or ROW_NUMBER/RANK and then WHERE the best (=1) or use a single line QUALIFY which is the same, but requires less layers, but is more intention dense.